# vsftpd and home directories of chrooted local users

Tags: linux, security, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

NOTE: Users are chrooted and their `local_root` is set to `/srv/ftp`.

Why vsftpd forces local chrooted users to have home directory? It will refuse to work if there is not any. And I've found the following in the code:

```
secutil.c:53  
/* Always do the chdir() regardless of whether we are chroot()'ing */
```

What is the purpose of that? Why should one chdir shortly to home and then to `local_root`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing because it's useful for the user to start off in their home directory when they connect, instead of being dropped into `/` (or somewhere else) and having to `cd` into their home directory most of the time.

The home directory should be taken from `/etc/passwd` though, so you can set it to anything you like (it doesn't have to be `/home/<username>`). You could make it `/tmp` or even `/` if you wanted to.

Comment: Please see my comment to the other answer and note that I've added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

What good is a chroot for if it drops you to `/` by default? The purpose of chrooting users to their home directory is to prevent them wandering around elsewhere -- the lack of homedir would defeat that and be horribly error prone.

Comment: There is an option local_root which I'm using, so the users are chrooted there. The question is why to shortly change to home before this.

Answer (score 1):

A `chroot` simply changes the root folder of the directory tree, so you can't `cd` a folder up from that point. Somehow developers have assumed `$home_folder` should be the `chroot` and packaged the two config variables together. It might be the answer for more than half of the ftp users out there, but for many it's not.

What if you want `/home/$DOMAIN` to be the `chroot` (`local_root`) and `/home/$DOMAIN/$USER` to be the landing folder? Then I would be told I am a special case or small majority that doesn't get to use `vsftpd`. Ethically, `local_root` should only be `chroot` and have nothing to do with where the user lands when logging in.